# loop through one group in regex (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex containing something like `([A-Za-z]\s)+`. It returns one group containing all the letters followed by a space. However, it keeps only the last element in the group for example if the text contains `a b c d`, I tried to print the group match but it returns only the letter (d). This is my program

```
while (m.find()) {
      L = m.group(1);
      System.out.println(L);
                  }
```

My question is why I only get letter (d) instead of all letters? Is it because They are all captured through one group? how can I correct that? How can I iterate through one group. For example, iterate through all matches detected as one group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that it matches all sequences of *one character followed by a space*.

In your example, `group()` would return the whole `a b c d` string. However when capturing braces are inside repetition (like your `+`), only the last captured value can be retrieved, hence `group(1)` returns `d`.

To fix your issue, just remove the `+` from your regex. This will make the `find()` succeed several times, and each time you will get a different match. In that case you might even drop the parenthesis and simply use `group()`.